# Free library for mounting *nix & mac file systems for .NET?

Tags: .net, filesystems, mount

My application is Microsoft.NET 3.5, C#. It works with windows file systems using .NET API like File.Exists, Directory.GetFiles/GetDirectories, File.ReadAllText and similar.

I need to have an ability to search and read files on another file systems, particularly, *nix and MacOS file systems,

Is there any free library enabling me to mount such file systems and work with them using .NET API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution would be a driver for Windows. There is a ext2/3 driver available on http://www.fs-driver.org/ but I don't know about a driver for the ext4 or any OSX filesystem.

Comment: Yes, seems that it would be harder for MacOS. There is MacDrive but it is commercial.